# Como quebrar linhas utilizando template string (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, concatenação-de-string, interpolação-de-string

Possuo uma requisição para o back-end e sua URL está bem grande.

```
this
  .$http
  .get(`backoffice/usuarios/${this.id}/grupo/${this.grupo}/filial/${this.filial}/multinivel/${this.multinivel}`)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.items = data
  })
})
```

Visto que estou utilizando [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) do Javascript ES6, gostaria de saber como realizo uma quebra de linhas sem que ele coloque os espaços (%20) na requisição.

Sei que posso quebrar em várias constantes utilizando `const`, mas gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de realizar a quebra de linha 
facilmente com ES6.

Já tentei com '/n', <kbd>enter</kbd> normal, e não funcionou.

A requisição é feita em um projeto Vuejs2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a ideia é somente facilitar a leitura podes fazer:

```js
const url = `
  backoffice/
  usuarios/
  ${this.id}/
  grupo/
  ${this.grupo}/
  filial/
  ${this.filial}/
  multinivel/
  ${this.multinivel}
`;

this
  .$http
  .get(url)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.items = data
  })
})
```

Se o `.get()` não limpar os espaços em branco e quebras de linha junta `.replace(/[\n\s]+/g, '')`.

```js
const url = `
  backoffice/
  usuarios/
  ${this.id}/
  grupo/
  ${this.grupo}/
  filial/
  ${this.filial}/
  multinivel/
  ${this.multinivel}
`.replace(/[\n\s]+/g, '');

this
  .$http
  .get(url)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.items = data
  })
})
```

Também podias fazer isso com uma array (seria a minha escolha neste caso):

```js
const url = [
  "backoffice",
  "usuarios",
  this.id,
  "grupo",
  this.grupo,
  "filial",
  this.filial,
  "multinivel",
  this.multinivel
].join('/');

this
  .$http
  .get(url)
  .then(({
    data
  }) => {
    this.items = data
  })
})
```